# How to generate more than two correlated series in R?

Tags: r, time-series, correlation

I'd like to generate more than two (i.e 3) correlated series, take an example when the series follows an IMA(1,1) process, at first I want to generate three correlated random errors `e[i]` and then I use the following equation to build the series: `d[i,] <- mu + d[i-1,] - theta*(e[i-1,])+e[i,]` 
this is what we need to do for two series, how can we develop it for more than two series?

```
library(mvtnorm)
rho <- 0.5
mu <- c(10,10)
phi <- c(0.2,0.8)
theta <- c(0.3,-0.7)
d <- ts(matrix(0,ncol=2,nrow=50))
e <- ts(rmvnorm(50,sigma=cbind(c(1,rho),c(rho,1))))
for(i in 2:50)
  d[i,] <- mu + phi*d[i-1,] - theta*(e[i-1,]+e[i,])
plot(d)
```

Comment: What did you try

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
library(mvtnorm)
rho1 <- 0.5
rho2 <- 0.3
rho3 <- -0.1
mu <- c(10,10,10)
phi <- c(0.2,0.8,0.6)
theta <- c(0.3,-0.7,0.1)
d <- ts(matrix(0,ncol=3,nrow=50))
e <- ts(rmvnorm(50,sigma=cbind(c(1,rho1,rho2),c(rho1,1,rho3),c(rho2,rho3,1))))
for(i in 2:50)
  d[i,] <- mu + phi*d[i-1,] - theta*(e[i-1,]+e[i,])
plot(d)
```

Frankly, judging by the questions you’ve been asking lately, you need to take some time to review some basic probability theory, and learn R, **before** addressing time series, which is not easy stuff.